# Ember data not getting relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm  using Ember 1.13.3 and ember-data 1.13.5.

I have 2 models with a relationship:

spot:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  image_src: DS.attr('string')
});
```

user:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  avatar: DS.attr('string'),
  spots: DS.hasMany('spot')
});
```

now I call in all the spots and loop over them. Everything display fine of the spot model; however, when I try to retrieve the user's username `spot.user.username` it doesn't work. I checked the network and not even a request is being sent out to `users/:user_id`.

I also tried adding `asyn: true`:

```
DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true})
```

but this also did not work. Is there a new way to do relationships in ember 1.13? I know that the belongsTo call is being reach because it appears as a deprecation in the ember console:

```
In Ember Data 2.0, relationships will be asynchronous by default. You must set `user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: false })` if you wish for a relationship remain synchronous.
```

Comment: have you tried changing `spot.user.user` to `spot.user.username` ? because that would be correct. maybe a typo here?

Comment: or do you side-load the users? or include them in the spots-json?

Comment: @Jeff sorry that was a typo. Also I don't do either side-load or embed them

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this as I fear I am having a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944227/ember-get-related-record-in-ember-data-1-13-8

Answer (score 0):

The async attribute has to be defined on both sides.

spot:

```
 import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.Model.extend({
      user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async:true}),
      description: DS.attr('string'),
      created_at: DS.attr('date'),
      image_src: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

The same thing on user:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  avatar: DS.attr('string'),
  spots: DS.hasMany('spot', {async: true})
});
```

Discussion about this topic:

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107