# Ember get related record in ember-data 1.13.8

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Pre ember-data 1.13.8 I was able to `get` related records with the following syntax (this is inside of a component to comply with embers move from views):

```
var user = this.get('user') // The user model is passed through to the component
var classifications = user.get("Classifications"); // This would be the related records
```

However in ember 1.13.8 `classifications` is now `undefined` whereas before it was an array of related records. I have followed the [transition guide](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html) but can't seem to find a reference to this change.

My `user` model looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    User: DS.attr('string'),
    Email: DS.attr('string'),
    PCTID: DS.attr('number'),
    Classifications: DS.hasMany('classification'),
});
```

and my `classification` model looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    Classification: DS.attr('string'),
    PostedBy: DS.attr('string'),
    DatePosted: DS.attr('isodate'),
    Bulletin: DS.attr('string'),
    ExpireDate: DS.attr('isodate'),
    Title: DS.attr('string'),
    User: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    UserClassification: DS.attr(),
});
```

Both the `user` and it's `classifiations` are being returned to the store and serialized into the following format:

```
{
   "data": {
      "type": "user",
      "id": 1361,
      "attributes": {
         "User": "foo",
         "Email": null,
         "PCTID": 1
      }
   },
   "included": [
      {
         "type": "classification",
         "id": 1,
         "attributes": {
            "Classification": "Room",
            "PostedBy": "P Hauser",
            "DatePosted": "2014-09-17T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Bulletin": "All data is fictitious",
            "ExpireDate": null,
            "Title": "Bar for foo",
            "User": 1361,
            "UserClassification": {
               "UserId": 1361,
               "ClassificationId": 1
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How should I be getting the related records in ember-data 1.13.8?

Comment: Is your user model loaded when you call `user.get("Classifications")` or is it still in flight?

Comment: `Classifications: DS.hasMany('classification', { async: true })`, you should also use lower case variables (unrelated just convention), what you want to do is always set relationships to `async: true`

Comment: @GJK The user model is always loaded with the classifications model, I've added the serialized version of the response.

Comment: @Kitler, The UpperCamelCase is due to the fact that I am working on a legacy system where the convention was to UpperCamelCase case (and I chickened out and kept it that way like a coward!! :p lol) . Also as far as I was aware `{ async: true }` is now the default and has thus been deprecated.

Comment: I don't think I'm formatting my JSON properly into a JSON-API formatted response, I haven't separated `relationships` out

Comment: Are you using one of the built-in adapters? If so, I would say that you're probably right - you're not serializing your relationships correctly.

Comment: @GJK yeh I'm extending from the RESTAdapter. I'll try and serialize the relationship differently. Jeez all the changes being added to ember is adding a lot of time to dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. It looks like with ember-data 1.13.8 and the move to JSON-API you need to **explicitly** include relationships in your JSON response and can't just let ember look after them for you by defining the relationship in your model.

*(Personally this will add a seemingly unnecessary development overhead, as I was relying and ember sorting the relationships out for me, instead of me having to figure out what is a related document from my API and then serialize them into a JSON-API format)*

My successfully formatted JSON looked like this:

```
{
   "data": {
      "type": "user",
      "id": 1361,
      "attributes": {
         "User": "foo",
         "Email": null,
         "PCTID": 1
      },
      "relationships": {
         "Classifications": {
             "data": [
                 {"id": 1, "type": "classification",}
             ]
         }
      }
   },
   "included": [
      {
         "type": "classification",
         "id": 1,
         "attributes": {
            "Classification": "Room",
            "PostedBy": "P Hauser",
            "DatePosted": "2014-09-17T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Bulletin": "All data is fictitious",
            "ExpireDate": null,
            "Title": "Bar for foo",
            "User": 1361,
            "UserClassification": {
               "UserId": 1361,
               "ClassificationId": 1
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```